# UIGestures vs manual control

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

Is it a true statement that `UIGesturesRecognizer` effectively replaced any manual control afforded to us by

```
- touchesBegan:withEvent:
– touchesMoved:withEvent:
– touchesEnded:withEvent:
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

Just looking for a confirmation here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that the methods is not going to be called, this is not true.

If you are saying that the `UIGesture` can do what this methods do, the answer is yes, with UIGestures you can do all that you can do with this methods you posted. And probably in an easy way to code :)

You can get the state of the gesture, the view and others.
And with the UIGestures is easy to know if is a tap, a longpress, a swipe, etc.

Take a look at the [Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Edit:

An example for you, to add a PanGesture, that will be handled after:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureHandler:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

your method that will handle the pan, will receive the gesture, and will look like:

```
-(void)panGestureHandler:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    CGPoint postionInView = [gesture translationInView:self.view];
    [yourView setCenter:postionInView];
}
```

Comment: Say, in the past, i had a gameLoop going at 1/60 a second to `drawRect` which, if `touchesMoved` would redraw object on screen at a new location. Is this approach overrated now with UIGestureRecognizer? (pan)

Comment: I edited the answer, I do not know if I exactly get your point.

Answer (score 1):

Only if their `cancelTouchesInView` property is set to YES (the default).

Comment: Um...if the property of the gesturerecognizer is set to YES it wil not call the manual methods, otherwise it will...